# I don't understand what these two variables do in the where section of a sum implementation using foldl

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm new to Haskell and I have a function here which uses `foldl` to sum the components of a list. I know there is an easier way to do this, but I'm just wondering how this specific code works.

```
Sum :: [Int] -> Int
Sum xs = foldl f base xs
  where
   f a x = (+) a x
   base  = 0
```

When I see this, I assume that `f a x` is used in pattern matching and that `f` would be the function applied by `foldl`, `a` would be the base, and `x` would be the list. But apparently for this function to work `f a x` must evaluate to an integer. I am just extremely confused on how this function works and was wondering what this `f a x` part does.

Comment: `f a x = (+) a x` is a function definition, and it means the exact same thing here as it does at the top level.

Comment: `(+) a x` is another way of writing `a+x`, so `f a x = a+x` is the addition function, taking two integers, and returning their integer sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foldl` works by taking one value from the list and passing it together with the currently accumulated result to the provided function and using its return value as the new accumulated result. Then repeating this by taking the next value from the list, until there are no more values in the list.

In this case the function is `f`, which takes two integers and returns its sum.

The initial value of the accumulated result has to specified, too, in order to pass it to the function for the first time it is called together with the first value in the list.

So regarding your confusion and your interpretation of `a` and `x`:

- `a` is not the base, it is the currently accumulated result (it is the base only for the *first time* the function is called).
- `x` is not the list, it is the next value from the list.

So in this case, assuming the list was `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, then `f` would be called 4 times:

- initial accumulated result = `base` = `0`
- `f 0 1` = new accumulated result = `1`
- `f 1 2` = new accumulated result = `3`
- `f 3 3` = new accumulated result = `6`
- `f 6 4` = final accumulated result = `10`